# SQL Error after runnning composer update

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, composer-php

I needed to run `composer update` to install laravelcollectives. After running it I got:

> QueryException in Connection.php line 651: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Field'id' is unknown where clause (SQL: select * from users where id = 4 limit 1)

and:

> PDOException in Connection.php line 319: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 field'id' is unknown where clause

There was no such error before the update. What could have gone wrong?!

Comment: Is there an `id` field in the `users` table?

Comment: I take it that it's meant to be the auto incremented id field, it may be named differently

Comment: No, there is not an `id` filed, there is userid...but before the update the field's name was the same

Comment: Try rename it as a basic test.

Comment: Just renamed the field as `id` and everything worked. Unfortunately I want the field to be named `userid` cuz I have other IDs in the DB. What should I do to remain the field's name?

Comment: You will have to find out where it updated the code to use `id` rather than `userid` I suppose.

Comment: @Matt Found it - Builder.php holds the field name

Comment: You should just need to add `protected $primaryKey = 'userid';` to your user model

Answer (score 1):

What you really did wrong is you ran `composer update` to **install** a package into a working project.

To install a new package into a already good working environment always use `composer require vendor/package:2.*` in your case e.g.:

```
composer require laravelcollective/html:5.2.*
```

#### Why never run `composer update` to install a package?

As the command `update` already says it **updates every package** required in your `composer.json` to the newest version (based on your `minimum-stability` and version tag). Yes it also installs new packages but if you run into errors after running `update` you never know what happened. Is it the new package which killed your working project or any of the also updated packages. So only run `update` if you really want to update and never if you want to install a package. Therefore use `composer require` as it only installs a new package but never touches existing packages.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info @Peh !